# Not able to add springframe work in maven project

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven

I am trying to add spring-core & spring-context in a maven project but upon build, I am getting following error, I am trying to access three repositories which are given in first 3 lines of the follwing compilation error :

```
[INFO] Downloading from : http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-context/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.pom
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/spring-context/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.pom
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-context/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 30.622 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-05T18:18:19+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project HelloWorldMaven: Could not resolve dependencies for project Demo:HelloWorldMaven:jar:0.1: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-context:pom:4.0.0.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): connect timed out -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

Following is my POM.xml in which I have added the dependencies :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>Demo</groupId>
      <artifactId>HelloWorldMaven</artifactId>
      <version>0.1</version>
      <name>Hello world demo</name>
      <description>Hello world demo</description>

      <properties>
        <org.springframework-core-version>4.0.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-core-version> 
        <org.springframework-context-version>4.0.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-context-version>
        <log4j-version>1.2.17</log4j-version>
        <junit-version>4.12</junit-version>
    </properties>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-core-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-context-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-version}</version>
        </dependency>       
      </dependencies>

      <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>


    </project>
```

Please help , I am not able to figure out what I am missing, I think I am not able to access the remote repositories.
Please help. Thanks In advance.

Comment: Network issue: `from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): connect timed out...`

Comment: what issue it could be ? because I am able to reach the page `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-context/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.pom` in my browser.

Comment: I want to ask one more question, I have springframework in my .m2 repository, then why during compilation, it is going over the central repository to fetch it ?

Comment: i have these file in my repository @ ${my_home}\.m2\repository\springframework\spring-context\4.0.0.RELEASE ==>
*_remote.repositories*,
*m2e-lastUpdated.properties*,
*spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar*,
*spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar.lastUpdated*,
*spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar.sha1*,
*spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.pom*,
*spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.pom.lastUpdated*,
*spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.pom.sha1*,
*spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar.lastUpdated*,
*spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar.lastUpdated*

Answer (score 1):

You're probably behind a proxy, or your current network requires a proxy, or your connection is shaky

`to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): connect timed out ->`

Comment: but if a use this URL -> `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-context/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.pom` in my browser then i am able to reach the page, it means that my network is allowing me to reach that, isn't it ?

Comment: I have springframework in my .m2 repository, then why is it going to central repository to fetch springframework  ? I have tried `mvn clean install -o` and adding `<localrepository>` tag, but still it is going to central repository, I dont know why !!

Comment: Browser can have their own proxy and command line/maven can have their own proxy. You either have to set the proxy/certificate that your browser is using or disable the one in maven entirely

Comment: I added proxy setting and ran with `clean install -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=my.host.add -DproxyPort=myport` the project is running fine now. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I added following in my *setting.xml*

```
    <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>my.host.address</host>
      <port>myPort</port>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

and ran the project with

> clean install -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=my.host.address -DproxyPort=myPort

And it worked !

Comment: Is this the correct way of doing it ? @Tan Kim Loong